# Convert yyyymmdd to date for record selection

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I'm a Crystal newbie with limited experience at SQL commands.

Here's my problem.

My database stores dates in the yyyymmdd numeric format.  I created a Date Range parameter field to allow the user to select a date range.  When I try to add the {?Date Range} to the record selection I get an error message that says "A number range is required here", apparently because my {?Date Range} field is looking for a date and not a number.  I believe what I have to do is convert my dates to a date format, but I don't know how to do that.

Could someone please tell me how to make this work?

Much appreciation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Crystal around to check the syntax , but generally you need to convert the daterange to numeric values and use theese values in your record selection formula

the TO value will be 
tonumber(totext(Maximum({?ParameterDateRange}),'yyyyMMdd'))

the FROM value will be 
tonumber(totext(Minimum ({?ParameterDateRange}),'yyyyMMdd'))

so the formula might be something like

```
{YourField} IN tonumber(totext(Minimum ({?DateRange}),'yyyyMMdd'))  TO tonumber(totext(Maximum({?DateRange}),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

You can also use < and > instead of between

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CDate` fucntion to convert numeric to Date.

```
CDate(ToNumber(Mid(ToText(20141231),1,4)),ToNumber(Mid(ToText(20141231),5,2)),ToNumber(Mid(ToText(20141231),7,2)))
```

Check the link for documentation

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic728.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{table.date} IN ToText(Minimum({?DateRange}),"yyyymmdd") TO ToText(Maximum({?DateRange}),"yyyymmdd")
```